# Recommendations for Survey + Customer Engagement tool

Tags: customer-service, surveys

We are currently trying out desk.com for a customer engagement tool.  Now we want to create surveys for our customers but desk.com doesn't offer this ability nor do they integrate with any other survey apps.

Can anyone recommend an integrated or semi-integrated solution for customer engagement with the ability to survey?  We are open to leaving desk.com and trying something else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ZenDesk? It integrates with Surveymonkey http://www.zendesk.com/apps/surveymonkey seems to be exactly what you are looking for.